# List of list of tuples to CSV string

Tags: python

Need to convert list of list of tuple data to CSV string:

```
mylist = [[(3, '051923', 'a1', '37', 0), (3, '051923', 'a1', '35', '72'), (3, '051924', 'a1', '33', '96')], [(3, '051923', 'a2', '7.00', 0), (3, '051923', 'a2', '6.80', '192')]]
```

To be convert to CSV string. Let's say:

```
3,051923,a1,37,0,\n3,051923,a1,35,72,\n3,051924,a1,33,96,\n3,051923,a2,7.00,0,\n3,051923,a2,6.80,192
```

I tried with below but it is not working:

```
'\n'.join(','.join([element if element else 'None' for element in tup]) for tup in mylist)
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for `join()`: _A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable,_ So: `','.join([str(element)....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is close but has two issues:

1. The inner list comprehension should flatten the sub-lists.
2. You're not converting elements to strings before joining.

Try this:

```py
'\n'.join(','.join(str(element) for element in tup) for sublist in mylist for tup in sublist)
```

Alternatively, you could use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) for an arguably more idiomatic approach.

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

output = StringIO()
csv_writer = csv.writer(output)
for sublist in mylist:
    csv_writer.writerows(sublist)

csv_string = output.getvalue().strip()
```

Either approach will give you your desired CSV:

```
3,051923,a1,37,0
3,051923,a1,35,72
3,051924,a1,33,96
3,051923,a2,7.00,0
3,051923,a2,6.80,192
```

Comment: You can use `sum(mylist, [])` to flatten `mylist` to a list of tuples.

Comment: @rochard4u Yeah, but that goes against PEP 20: "Readability counts" IMO.

Also `sum(mylist, [])` is less efficient since it is O(n^2). If you don't want to use a nested comprehension you should use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.